# message from firefox add-on contentscript to the surrounding page

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm porting a Chrome extension to Firefox which uses a content script to call a method in the surrounding page via postMessage. The page contains an event listener like

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
   console.log(event)
}, false);
```

I'm trying to send a message from a firefox add-on sdk content-script using a call:

```
self.postMessage({toPage: true, type: "initAck"}, "*");
```

**BTW** I tried using directly windows.postMessage but I get an exception saying I should use `self.postMessage`

I listen to this message on the add on `main.js` and post it via the `worker.postMessage` method but the message never arrives to the page's event listener:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
   include: "*",
   contentScriptWhen: "start",
   contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery.min.js"),
                       self.data.url("myscript.js")],
   onAttach: function(worker) {
      worker.on("message", function(addonMessage) {
           worker.postMessage(addonMessage, "*");
      });
   }
});
```

In general, is there a way for a firefox context script to access the surrounding page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question, however in the [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.13/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html) is described how to send message from the content script to the page script:

```
document.defaultView.postMessage("Message from content script", "http://my-domain.org/");
```

Hope it helps!